# VoiceXML UCMA Error when deploying to server

Tags: c#, .net, ucma

I have deployed a sample project to a Windows 2008 virtual server that does not have any audio set up.

I have installed the UCMA 3.0 runtime.  This application runs on a Windows 7 64 bit development laptop.

I am receiving the following exception.

```
    Error: Recognizer setting not supported by recognizer.
    Stacktrace:    at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer.SetProperty(ISpRecognizer sapiRecognizer, String name, Object value)
                   at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<SetPropertyNum>b__0()
                   at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.UpdateRecognizerSetting(String settingName, Int32 updatedValue)
                   at Microsoft.SpeechServer.Core.SpeechRecognizer..ctor(ICallProxy callProxy)
                   at Microsoft.SpeechServer.Core.TelephonySession..ctor(ICallProxy callProxy)
                   at Microsoft.SpeechServer.Core.ApplicationHost..ctor(ICallProxy callProxy, Uri vxmlUrl)
                   at Microsoft.Speech.VoiceXml.Browser.RunWorker()
                   at Microsoft.Speech.VoiceXml.Browser.Run(Uri vxmlPage, CookieContainer container)
```

This happens when from this block of code:

```
InitializeVoiceXmlBrowswer();

var helloWorldUri = new Uri(new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\"), "HelloWorld.vxml");

VoiceXmlBrowser.SetAudioVideoCall(call);

VoiceXmlResult voiceResult = VoiceXmlBrowser.Run(helloWorldUri, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was sloved be using a server with a sound card.

Answer (score -1):

Could be that you need to specify the language pack that you have installed - see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600390/microsoft-speech-recognition-platform)

Comment: Did you follow the link to this question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600390/microsoft-speech-recognition-platform