# PlatformNotSupportedException while using Microsoft System.Speech.Recognition

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have a one problem in my program. I Want to convert speech to text and I have a this code:

```
Choices sList = new Choices();
sList.Add(new string[] { "hello" });
Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
try {
    sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
    sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
    sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
    sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    sRecognize.Recognize();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

But when I using it, Visual Studio give an exception "platformnotsupportedexception" And say "The recognizer is not installed." I have a microphone, But I don't know why this don't job. Please Help Me.

Comment: Related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741053/platformnotsupportedexception-using-net-speech-recognition

Answer (score 0):

`platformnotsupportedexception` The exception that is thrown when a feature does not run on a particular platform. This means that you probably didn't install Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11 Requirements and Installation. Found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362873.aspx

Comment: Speech Platform Runtime 11 and Speech Platform SDK 11 has installed, but problem don't go

Comment: Could it be you're build 64bit with 32bit sdk, or otherwise?

Comment: I have a 64bit and install x64

Answer (score 0):

Are you using System.Speech.Recognition or Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?  [They're different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982910/175201). If you're using Speech Platform Runtime/SDK 11, then you need to be using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.

Also, you probably need to specify a [cultureinfo when creating your recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611939/175201).

Comment: using System.Speech.Recognition;

Comment: There are some additional framework or library that you can use to implement speech to text?

Comment: @user2800980 - You mentioned Speech Platform Runtime 11 and Speech Platform SDK 11 - those are server recognizers that require the use of Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.

Comment: Microsoft. don't have a speech

Comment: @user2800980 - I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @user2800980 - Add it as a reference; assuming you installed the Speech Platform SDK 11 in the default location, go to Solution Explorer, right click References; click Add Reference; click Browse (near the bottom); navigate to c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\V11.0\Assembly; select Microsoft.Speech.dll.